# Instagram "User started following you" type notification is not showing, but all anothers are showing

Tags: instagram

I am using the latest version of IOS and Instagram App to current date (16.05.2023) on my iPhone. In my Instagram App i have 3 accounts added. For one of those accounts, from 2 months i do not receive notifications when somebody follows me (...started following you). I receive all another type notifications, but when somebody follows me, only the count of followers in increased, but there is no notification for that.

Do somebody know what can be the reason??

(ALL IPHONE AND INSTAGRAM NOTIFICATIONS ARE **ON**)

I have tried to reinstall the instagram app, to restart the iphone, to logout and login again, to stop and start again the notifications..

Comment: This isn't Tech Support; it's Stack Overflow.